# How to reset auto increment in laravel user deletion?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have been struggling to find out a way to reset the auto increment value in Laravel 4 but it seems that this functionality is not embedded in laravel 4 at least for now.
so i did it this way:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);

                if ($user)  {
                    if ($user->delete()){

                    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = '.(count(User::all())+1).';');

                    echo json_encode('User Was Deleted Successfully..');
                    }   
            }
```

each time i delete a user from the database i set the auto increment pointer to the number of all users +1.

if anybody has a better solution inform me please..

Comment: There is never any need to change the auto increment when deleting records.

Comment: Well when i have 15 users and i delete tha last 5 then the new user will be assigned the id of 16 but i want to start from 10

Comment: Why do you want it to restart?  There is no functional need for that.  If you really want to do it, you have to do it the way you already did, with raw SQL.

Comment: well why let the auto increment starting at a different value from the current number of users?

Comment: the auto increment isn't designed to be used as a count of the items in the table.. it's only supposed to be a unique identifier.  Could you explain why you need to reset it?

Comment: i would like the id to be displaying the actual number of the user in the list and not just a number.
so if i have 40 users that should be 40 ids 1-40 not 1-34545

Comment: You're wasting your time.  Just finish the app.

Comment: Your table's primary key should have nothing to do with the number of rows in the table.  Let's say you insist on trying to make this work (which it won't).  Every time you delete a user and reindex the table, you would then have to update every instance of user id in every other table where they appear.  That would be a monumentally bad design.  If you want to know how many users you have, do SELECT COUNT(some_colum) FROM your_table.

Comment: and what will happen if you have 40 users, and delete user with id 20... you're going to have to employ some extremely complicated logic to find and update everyone with id > 20.. this is only going to lead to problems in the future!

Comment: OK ok guys.. probably you convinced me not to change the marker of auto increment.
though its frustrating that there is no logic to "auto fill" the gaps between ids

Comment: if you're really that concerned about the id, use a GUID like  "52a62c65-e978-4d32-abb0-1b888e876123" as the primary id key. $table->string('id', 36)->primary(). Then you won't have to worry about numbers matching up.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Like everyone else replied, there is not really a need to move the counter back when you delete a row. You can however `truncate` a table which **will delete all the table rows** and reset the counter.

You cannot `truncate` a table that has `Foreign Key Constraints` applied on it (`truncate` is not the same as `delete` which simply deletes all the rows while **keeping** the auto-increment counter.).

Hence, while using `foreign key constrains`, MySQL might stop you from truncating a table which has `foreign key constraints` applied to it.

You can perform the following steps to achieve what you want, but beware, there may be a risk to your data integrity. I only use it for my **testing purposes**.

1. Edit the `DatabaseSeeder` class (which is available at `app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`) as follows:

   ```
   <?php
   class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
       /**
       * Run the database seeds.
       *
       * @return void
       */
       public function run()
       {
           Eloquent::unguard();

           // Disable Foreign key check for this connection before running seeders
           DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

           $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
           // ...

           // FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is supposed to only apply to a single
           // connection and reset itself but I like to explicitly
           // undo what I've done for clarity
           DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now the Table Seeder classes (Example, `UserTableSeeder` in this case, which should be created at `app/database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php`) can call truncate table(s) as follows:

   ```
   <?php
   class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

       public function run()
       {
           // Truncate the table.
           DB::table('users')->truncate();


           // The auto-increment has been reset.
           // Now we can start adding users.
           User::create(
               array(
                   'email' => 'example@domain.com',
                   'password' => Hash::make('test')
               )
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: yes that is if i want to truncate the table.
but what i wanted was the next auto_increment_value to continue where the last u_id is :D

Comment: @aimiliano Then you can use `DB::table('users')->delete();`? :)

Answer (score 16):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function refreshDB()
{
    $max = DB::table('users')->max('id') + 1; 
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT =  $max");
}

// Note: This solution is for resetting the auto_increment of the table without truncating the table itself
```

Comment: You can actually just do AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 wand it works

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's smart or not, but this will cleanup your table.

```
public function cleanup($table_name)
{       
    DB::statement("SET @count = 0;");
    DB::statement("UPDATE `$table_name` SET `$table_name`.`id` = @count:= @count + 1;");
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `$table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
}
```

MySQL will set the AUTO_INCREMENT to last+1
If you've set your foreign keys to ON UPDATE CASCADE the children will know about the changes and cascade the update.

This stuff takes server time and gives you little in return. I think that's why you're getting loads of "don't waist your time" responses?
For a count you should use ->count() and not the last id.

I also don't know if the statements should be within a transaction to prevent errors when users are added while your statements are running.

Comment: What if one decides to create migrations that insert predefined data? If you rollback your migration, shouldn't you reset any auto inserted IDs as well to a state before the migrations ran?

Comment: @georaldc You mean seeding? I didn't find a smart way to seed with laravel. It's one way. Mixing seedings and migrations is asking for trouble if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `PostgreSQL`:

```
public function resetAutoincrement()
{
    $max = DB::table('users')->max('id') + 1;
    DB::statement('ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH ' . $max);
}
```