# Laravel seeder sets first record with ID 2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, seeding

I am trying to seed my database via **DatabaseSeeder** Laravel, but when it seeds the database, the first row has ID 2 instead of 1.

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
public function run()
{

    foreach ($this->to_truncate as $table) {
        DB::table($table)->truncate();
    }

  $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
}
```

**UsersTableSeeder.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory('App\User', 1)->create();
    }
}
```

**ModelFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'full_name' => 'Jakub Kohout',
        'username' => 'Admin',
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('Uchiha'),
        'role_id' => 1
    ];
});
```

My seeding process looks like this:

```
heroku run php artisan migrate
heroku run php artisan db:seed
```

This is the migration for my User model:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('full_name');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: please explain (show artisan commands, tinker commands) how do you run your seeds && factories (edit question)

Comment: is your migration for user model default (from Laravel) or is it modified?

Comment: no it's modified and just added it to the question.

Comment: Go to your local development and open up terminal use `$ php artisan tinker`. Meanwhile go your phpmyadmin or Sequel Pro and manually truncate users table + reset autoinctement count. In Psy Shell (tinker) type `factory(App\User::class, 1)->create()`. What is the output?

Comment: so I manually truncated table in sequelPro then reseted autoincrement count, but the thinker still say this

App\User {#752
     full_name: "Jakub Kohout",
     username: "Admin",
     email: "test@gmail.com",
     role_id: 1,
     updated_at: "2016-02-07 11:53:19",
     created_at: "2016-02-07 11:53:19",
     id: 2,
   }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102831/discussion-between-kyslik-and-jakub-kohout).

Answer (score 2):

if your ID is auto incremental and you put 1 row before then delete it, then the second row ID will be 2, it is mysql not laravel. and you can solve this issue by dropping table then create it again with auto increment begin with 1.

or you can this query:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: You also can TRUNCATE TABLE table_name before seeding

Comment: before each seed I'm truncating all tables for that reason.

        foreach ($this->to_truncate as $table) {
            DB::table($table)->truncate();
        }

Comment: is your table in a relation?

Comment: so, try to put this before truncate DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546253/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-laravel-user-deletion

Answer (score 1):

I'll presume that you are using MySQL - if so you can run following command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
```

and it should return something like:

```
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 10    |
| auto_increment_offset    | 2     |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Offset is whats giving you headaches. Both of this can be set by running (from within MySQL):

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=1;
```